# How can I open an Activity in the Wikitude Client Tracker Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wikitude

I have a problem with my first real android project. I need to start a new activity from this one down there, when the client tracker does recognize a target. It would mean the world to me if someone could help me.

The things I already tried, ended always in a disaster... probably because I have no idea what I’m doing (thats also the reason I'm not posting what I have tried)

P.S. I used the Wikitude native Api libary

```
 package com.ia.grafp.maturapp2_2;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ia.grafp.maturapp2_2.rendering.external.CustomSurfaceView;
import com.ia.grafp.maturapp2_2.rendering.external.Driver;
import com.ia.grafp.maturapp2_2.rendering.external.GLRenderer;
import com.wikitude.WikitudeSDK;
import com.wikitude.WikitudeSDKStartupConfiguration;
import com.wikitude.common.camera.CameraSettings;
import com.wikitude.common.rendering.RenderExtension;
import com.wikitude.common.tracking.RecognizedTarget;
import com.wikitude.rendering.ExternalRendering;
import com.wikitude.tracker.ClientTracker;
import com.wikitude.tracker.ClientTrackerEventListener;
import com.wikitude.tracker.Tracker;

/**

 */
public class ArchitectView extends AppCompatActivity implements ClientTrackerEventListener, ExternalRendering {


    private static final String TAG = "ArchitectView";

    private WikitudeSDK _wikitudeSDK;
    private CustomSurfaceView _view;
    private Driver _driver;
    private GLRenderer _glRenderer;
    private boolean tracking;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _wikitudeSDK = new WikitudeSDK(this);
        WikitudeSDKStartupConfiguration startupConfiguration
                = new WikitudeSDKStartupConfiguration
                (WikitudeSDKConstants.WIKITUDE_SDK_KEY,
                        CameraSettings.CameraPosition.BACK,
                        CameraSettings.CameraFocusMode.CONTINUOUS);
        _wikitudeSDK.onCreate(getApplicationContext(), this, startupConfiguration);
        ClientTracker tracker
                = _wikitudeSDK.getTrackerManager().create2dClientTracker
                ("file:///android_asset/magazine.wtc");
        tracker.registerTrackerEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        _wikitudeSDK.onResume();
        _view.onResume();
        _driver.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        _wikitudeSDK.onPause();
        _view.onPause();
        _driver.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        _wikitudeSDK.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderExtensionCreated(final RenderExtension renderExtension_) {
        _glRenderer = new GLRenderer(renderExtension_);
        _view = new CustomSurfaceView(getApplicationContext(), _glRenderer);
        _driver = new Driver(_view, 30);
        setContentView(_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExtendedTrackingQualityUpdate(final Tracker tracker_, final String targetName_, final int oldTrackingQuality_, final int newTrackingQuality_) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorLoading(final ClientTracker clientTracker_, final String errorMessage_) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onErrorLoading: " + errorMessage_);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrackerFinishedLoading(final ClientTracker clientTracker_, final String trackerFilePath_) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTargetRecognized(final Tracker tracker_, final String targetName_) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracking(final Tracker tracker_, final RecognizedTarget recognizedTarget_) {
        _glRenderer.setCurrentlyRecognizedTarget(recognizedTarget_);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTargetLost(final Tracker tracker_, final String targetName_) {
        _glRenderer.setCurrentlyRecognizedTarget(null);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onTargetRecognized(final Tracker tracker_, final String targetName_) {

             Intent i = new Intent(ArchitectView.this, yourActivityClass.class);
             startactivity(i);
    }
```

I don't know if this answer your question, but that is the way of starting a new activity.

Comment: Thank you. This code solved my problem: 


        startActivity(new Intent(ArchitectView.this, MainActivity.class));